# Reset password in laravel 4.1 : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am setting up a password reminder feature in my laravel 4.1 app and everything  seems to work find till when I submit the reset form. When I submit the password reset form, I get this error:

```
ErrorException

Trying to get property of non-object

 open: C:\\xampp\WWW\myApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\DatabaseReminderRepository.php
```

The manual is my guide. I have successfully send the reset link via e-mail and got the form through the link. But the above error arise upon submission of the form. Please help. Thanks.

OK. This is my code in the Remind Controller responsible for password reset.

```
public function postReset()
{
    $credentials = Input::only(
        'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
    );

    $response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
    {

        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        $user->save();
    });

    switch ($response)
    {
        case Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
        case Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

        case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
            return Redirect::to('/');
    }
  }
```

NB: it was generate using
 php art... auth:reminders-controller according to the laravel doc.
Thanks for making the comments.

Comment: Can you give us some more informations ? What do you do after the form is submitted ? Can you show us the controller ? or the form ? It's not enough info to draw a conclusion

Comment: Yeah, you really need to show some code, we can't *guess* what your code looks like or what you're doing.

Comment: I am making use of mongoDb as my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I review my DatabaseReminderRepository.php

I checked $reminder with dd($reminder) and bring me an array so i've change with $reminder['created_at'];

```
protected function reminderExpired($reminder) {
// this $reminder->created_at into this $reminder['created_at']
// $createdPlusHour = strtotime($reminder->created_at) + $this->expires;
    $createdPlusHour = strtotime($reminder['created_at']) + $this->expires;
    return $createdPlusHour < $this->getCurrentTime();
}
```